# Can I use 18/5 thermostat wire to connect a thermostat to a baseboard heater?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, heater, baseboard

Cadet Electric Baseboard heater safely hard-wires for 1500-Watt at 240-Volt or 1125 Watt at 208-Volt
Thermostat controls up to 5280-Watt at 240-Volt or 2640-Watt at 120-Volt
Easily replaces most line voltage wall-mounted thermostats
Double pole (4-wire) thermostat with positive off position
22 Amp thermostat

Comment: thank you. I thought that was the thermostat I had to use, I haven't even purchased units yet. Is there a better route to take?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not.  The 18/5 thermostat wire is intended for  low voltage, either millivolt or 24-volt AC thermostats intended for use with gas furnaces or heat pumps.

With line voltage heaters like the Cadet, you normally run full-power house wiring (12/2 or 10/2) from the circuit breaker to the thermostat.  And then, more 12/2 or 10/2 from the thermostat to the heater(s).

There are other ways to do it, but if you want to use a 4-wire thermostat or a smart line voltage thermostat, that's how you have to do it.

Comment: Wow, did you get that right instantly or not!?  The OP could accomplish it two ways, either wire up a contactor, LV T-stat and transformer to power the T-stat, or get  a line voltage t-stat that is programmable.  They are not common, but available.     Of course all of this would have to be properly housed and permanently accessible, which may be a practical challenge.

Comment: @George yeah, I love my relays (I love 'em a lot more when they're at the panel and not in the bedroom, who wants to hear that?)... but I wanted to keep it simple.  A branch to the thermostat would require at least /3 cable of the size of the mains feeds.